# How to fix string.replace is not a Function in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have some data and want to replace the $ with a space I am currently using the code below

```
variable - theirValue = data.lowest_price.replace("$",'').trim();
```

It has a problem with the .replace and says data.replace is not a function

Here is the Full code on where it is located

```
const market = require('steam-market-pricing');
theirValue= 0;

market.getItemsPrice(730, 'MP9 | Storm (Minimal Wear)', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    theirValue += data.lowest_price.replace("$",'').trim()
})
```

What the code above returns is below in json form

```
{ 'MP9 | Storm (Minimal Wear)':
{ success: true,
 lowest_price: '$0.05',
 volume: '185',
 median_price: '$0.03' } }
```

and that is how it is in the file how i have it in the code i am doing getting steam market prices for items that i put in place of the p90 name but i want it to show just price (ex. 1.00) not $price (ex. $1.00)
It says in the console that replace is not a Function

Comment: What is `data.lowest_price`? It might not be a string in the case where you're trying to use it

Comment: i up dated the question i am commenting so you know that i have added more to the question i asked

Comment: But we still don’t know the value of data.lowest_price

Comment: i think i figured out what you meant by that question i put the output of the code i have above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this:

```
data['MP9 | Storm (Minimal Wear)'].lowest_price // '$0.05'
data.lowest_price                               // undefined
```

Is `market.getItemsPrice()` supposed to use the second parameter to return the object containing `lowest_price`?

---

Your comment raises a second question about type casting in JavaScript. Remember that `lowest_price` is stored as a string. When adding two different types--number and string--it will try to cast values if it can:

```
theirValue += '0.05'                 // number + string --> string: '00.05'
theirValue += parseFloat('0.05', 10) // number + number --> number: 0.05
theirValue += +'0.05'                // number + number --> number (unary operator)
```

Comment: ok i tried the data['MP9 | Storm (Minimal Wear)'].lowest_price and it had the output with the var theirValue was 0$0.05 how do i fix that? i want it to have an output of a number ont with the $

Comment: It sounds like you found the answer to your main question. I'll edit to answer the new question on why you're getting '0$0.05'.